# Add padding to IP addresses in PostgreSQL SELECT Query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I've already got a method for excel, but I want the padding to be done via the query to reduce my effort later in the process

#### Excel Example

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2,1)-1),"000") & "." & TEXT(MID(A2,FIND(
".",A2,1)+1,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2,1)+1)-FIND(".",A2,1)-1),"000")
& "." & TEXT(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2,1)+1)+1,FIND(".",A2,
FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2,1)+1)+1)-FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2,1)+1)-1),
"000") & "." & TEXT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2,FIND(
".",A2,1)+1)+1)),"000")
```

I tried searching the PostgreSQL documentation but nothing was obvious on converting to padded

I also investigated potentially doing a CAST as I have done for hostnames utilizing regex

#### Hostname CAST Example for PostgreSQL

```
UPPER(regexp_replace(da.host_name, '([\.][\w\.]+)', '', 'g')) AS hostname
```

But, I am hitting a roadblock here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share sample data and your desired result. That excel formula is a nightmare and I can't imagine many people are going to bother parsing that. Without parsing it, I'm not clear what you mean by "add padding to ip address"

Comment: Instead of 1.1.1.1.   001.001.001.001

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that by "Padding an IP" you are wanting to lpad 0's to the front of each ip part.

Using regexp_replace you can do the following:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace('19.2.2.2', '([0-9]{1,3})', '00\1', 'g'), '(0*)([0-9]{3})', '\2', 'g');
```

Optionally if you are on 9.4 or newer you could get crafty with `UNNEST()` or `REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE()` and the new `WITH ORDINALITY` keyword to split each ip part (and the key from the table) out to its own row. Then you can `lpad()` with 0's and `string_agg()` it back together using the ordinal that was preserved in the `unnest` or `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
user=# SELECT * FROM test;
 id |      ip
----+--------------
  1 | 19.16.2.2
  2 | 20.321.123.1
(2 rows)

user=# SELECT id, string_agg(lpad(ip_part, 3, '0'),'.' ORDER BY rn) FROM test t, regexp_split_to_table(t.ip, '\.') WITH ORDINALITY s(ip_part, rn) GROUP BY id;
 id |   string_agg
----+-----------------
  1 | 019.016.002.002
  2 | 020.321.123.001
(2 rows)
```

Theoretically this would work in older versions since it seems like ordinals are preserved during `unnest()`, but it feels more like luck and I wouldn't productionize any code that depends on that.

Comment: I am on 11.x for postges